# What are the differences between independent and party-affiliated MPs and candidates?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, member-of-parliament

What rights/privileges, duties and handicaps do UK MPs and parliamentary election candidates who are affiliated with parties (Conservative, Labour, Liberal-Democrat etc.) have, which independent MPs and candidates do not?

Note:  I'm naturally asking about privileges and duties which such MPs would not have as rank-and-file party members.

Answer (score 4):

In a strict legal sense, the biggest differences I'm aware of is that the candidate of a registered party are allowed to choose to use the name, description and emblem of their party on their ballot paper, but must be issued a certificate from the party's nominating officer to do so (which effectively means they must be selected following the party's own selection procedure). See [here](https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/sites/default/files/pdf_file/UKPGE-Part-2b-Standing-as-a-party-candidate.pdf) for party candidates versus [here](https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/sites/default/files/pdf_file/UKPGE-Part-2a-Standing-as-an-independent-candidate.pdf) for independents.

In a practical sense, since the House of Commons sets its own rules via the will of the majority, the major parties (particularly the big two of the Conservative party and the Labour Party) have control over who takes jobs such as Speaker & Deputy speaker, as well as the membership of the [various committees](https://www.parliament.uk/business/committees/) and even who gets the nicer offices. Similarly (somewhat obviously) the Prime Minister will not be an independent MP, and the Leader of Her Majesty's Loyal Opposition will come from the largest party not in government.

In a soft sense, party MPs are generally expected to adhere to the party line on all major issues, both in their public comments and their voting record, and a significant amount of [parliamentary party work](https://www.parliament.uk/about/mps-and-lords/principal/whips/) can go into achieving this. However, given that the only punishments are a reduction in party seniority, or removal of the whip (i.e., throwing them out), this doesn't always follow.

Comment: 1. If you're an independent, can't you choose your own emblem and description though? 2. Can independent MPs not join any committees voluntarily?

Comment: @einpoklum 1: Iirc you have to be in a party (even of only one member) to have an emblem and description *on the ballot*. 2: Committee memberships are appointed, an independant *could* be appointed to a committee, but the parties will prioritise their members.

Comment: @einpoklum My recollection is that a UK registered party needs at least two people to fill various required posts, and that independents are allowed the description "Independent", but otherwise I believe Caleth is right. For more details see https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/sites/default/files/pdf_file/intro-registration-rp.pdf and https://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/ResearchBriefing/Summary/SN04400

Comment: @Caleth: You're probably right, It looks that's what [Lord Buckethead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Buckethead) has done.

Answer (score 0):

Another benefit of being a member of a political party rather than running as an Independent is that you become eligible for 'Short Money' - funding provided to opposition parties to support them in their parliamentary duties.

These funds are only [available](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/sn01663/) to "all opposition *parties* in the House of Commons that secured either two seats, or one seat and more than 150,000 votes, at the previous General Election."

The Institute for Government also [states](https://www.instituteforgovernment.org.uk/explainers/public-funding-political-parties) that "Independent MPs – those without a party affiliation – are not eligible for any public funds".

As the largest parliamentary constituency by population in the UK is the Isle of Wight, with just over 100,000 voters, it is, however, impossible for a party only contesting one seat to become eligible for the payments on their own - it would require at least one other seat to be contested.